# Javascript Resize all Images

Tags: javascript, image, resize

im trying to resize all images on a page. After googleing 1 day, I ended in the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onresize = function(){
var images = document.images;
images.style.width = "100%";
};


-->
</script>
```

Could someone tell me please, why this wont work? :/

Greets SG

Comment: I know this is really stupid but in your real code do you have your code commented out because in your example it is <!--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points why dont you use css for this, im not sure why you would need to use javascript.

```
img{width:100%;}
```

Second in your example your code is commented out and also images creates an array that you will need to loop through seeZoltan Toth answer

Comment: He he no worries when ever possible keep styling out of javascript :)